# Как вывести в консоль информацию о том какие модули импортированы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, модули

Пробовал вот так `print(ext_module.__name__)`. По аналогии с выводом информации о основном модуле `print(__name__)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4858100/10941639.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Тут в `print(ext_module.__name__)` вместо ext_module название импортированного модуля и его выведет в консоль.